# CSSで、兄弟要素の最初の一文字が指定文字列だった場合のセレクタ

Tags: css

下記状態のpタグをcssで指定したいのですが、可能ですか？

```
<blockquote></blockquote>
<p>※</p>
```

Comment: 最終的に"＊が先頭にある`p`要素"を指定したいのは分かりますが、兄弟要素をどういう風に関係させたいのかが曖昧です。まずは`blockquote`要素の次の`p`要素なのか、それとも`blockquote`要素の兄弟である`p`要素なのかを明確にする必要があるように思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

blockquote と同じ階層で，すぐ下にある p という指定であれば隣接兄弟コンビネータを使えます．

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#%E9%9A%A3%E6%8E%A5%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E5%85%84%E5%BC%9F

ただし，「最初の文字が 〇〇 だったら」は CSS だけだと厳しいと思います．
JavaScript を使って，条件をみたした要素にクラスを追加するなどして， CSS を当てると良いと思います．